# How is CVE-2016-6787 a UAF bug in Linux kernel?

Tags: vulnerability

From the [explanation video](https://youtu.be/U2qvK1hJ6zg?t=1138) of the Linux kernel vulnerability CVE-2016-6787, I don't understand is though `put_ctx` isn't inside a mutex, there's an `atomic_dec_and_test` inside `put_ctx` at the very beginning. `kfree_rcu` is only invoked if `atomic_dec_and_test` returns `1`. How come two threads become racy then? Where is `ctx` getting used after the free operation?